# Method to solve long differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(D^3-2D^2-5D+6)y=2e^{x}+4e^{3x}+7e^{-2x}+8e^{2x}+15$$

The complementary solution is :$ae^{x}+be^{3x}+ce^{-2x}$.

For the particular solution I get the form : 
$d_1+d_2xe^{x}+d_3xe^{-2x}+d_4e^{2x}+d_5xe^{3x}$

Proceeding after this becomes difficult as too many terms are getting involved. Is there a shorter method to solve such questions? I don't have any knowledge except trial solution method.

Comment: The Method of Undetermined Coefficients is standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $p(D)(xe^{rx})=xe^{rx}p(r)+e^{rx}p'(r)$, and if $r$ is a characteristic root of $p(D)$, then the first term is zero.

Next you can compose the particular solution as sum of the particular solutions for each term resp. for each exponential factor on the right separately.

Thus for the constant $15e^{0x}$ you get $15=d_1p(0)=6d_1\implies d_1=\frac52$ and for the term $2e^x$ you get $2=d_2p'(1)=(3\cdot 1^2-2⋅2\cdot 1^1-5⋅1^0)d_2=-6d_2\implies d_2=-\frac13$ etc.

Comment: Why $15\stackrel{?}{=}d_1p(0)$, since $p(D)(15e^{0x})=0$. Your demonstration is not clear to me. Can you clear it little bit$?$

Comment: The exponentials are linearly independent, thus do not influence each other. To solve $p(D)y=15$, the trial solution is $y=d_1$ which results in $p(0)d_1=15$. To solve $p(D)y=8e^{2x}$ the trial solution is $y=d_4e^{2x}$ so that $d_4e^{2x}p(2)=8e^{2x}$, etc.

Comment: Aha. One last question, if the exponentials are linearly dependent then is it possible to solve it like$?$

Comment: @emonhossain : Your last comment is incomplete. You can also insert all terms at once and then sort the terms by exponentials, each such grouping then has to be zero.

Comment: To solve p(D)y=15, the trial solution is y=d1 which results in p(0)d1=15. To solve p(D)y=8e2x the trial solution is y=d4e2x so that d4e2xp(2)=8e2x,   How do you decide what to substitute for D?Like you took D=0 for first then D=2

Comment: @Aladdin $p(D)(xe^{\color{red}{r}x})=xe^{\color{red}{r}x}p(\color{red}{r})+e^{\color{red}{r}x}p'(\color{red}{r})$ can you notice that.

Comment: @Aladdin : $D$ is the differentiation operator. Thus $D(xf(x))=(xf(x))'=f(x)+xf'(x)=[(xD+1)f](x)$ and by induction $D^kx=xD^k+kD^{k-1}$. In the same way, $D(e^{rx})=re^{rx}$ so that $D^k(e^{rx})=r^ke^{rx}$ which implies the cited rules.

Comment: Can u tell the name of this method and any derivation source? I am curious as my teacher has done something similar but she didn't do derivation?

Comment: @Abhinav : You need to be more specific. The overall method discussed is known as "method of undetermined coefficients" (or "intelligent guessing"). Using polynomials in the operator is a common abbreviation using commutative algebra and only possible when the coefficients are constant, as, as already mentioned, $[D,x]=Dx-xD=1$, $D$ and $x$ do not commute. There is a structural connection to similar transformations in the Laplace transform.